# Can I cUrl a file from the web to Amazon S3?

Tags: file-io, curl, amazon-s3, data-transfer

Is there a way to transfer a file from the web directly to my Amazon S3 account?

For example, I want to transfer a large RDF file from www.data.gov directly to Amazon S3 without having to download the file to my local machine first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server somewhere that will execute the curl command.  The easiest way is probably to use this a tool that I wrote for AWS EC2: https://github.com/mjhm/cURLServer.  You can check out the docs on a live version at http://ec2-204-236-157-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/